# What API calls are involved in opening a port in the Windows Firewall?

Tags: winapi, windows-firewall

I have a batch file that installs WinVNC in about 1 second and starts up the service.  However, I still have to manually go into the Windows Firewall and open a port to allow connections.  How can I do that programmatically?

If I could do it from inside the batch file, that would be ideal, but I'm ok writing an EXE if that's necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me [google that](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&safe=off&client=firefox-a&rls=org.mozilla%3Aen-US%3Aofficial&hs=KPB&q=batch+%22windows+firewall%22&btnG=Search) for you:
http://www.windowsecurity.com/articles/Customizing-Windows-Firewall.html

This page includes a multitude of ways to customize the firewall, among those the use of `netsh.exe` that seem to give command line access to windows firewall.

Answer (score 2):

Windows Firewall has its own API for that purpose: [Windows Firewall and Windows Firewall with Advanced Security](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366453.aspx).  Look at the INetFwOpenPorts::Add() method.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a good resource that I have used multiple times in the past.  I know it's the typical 'point to the RTFM site', but really, it is a good resource and I have used it successfully.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366415(VS.85).aspx

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

shoosh googled it for me and I came up with this, which works perfectly.

```
netsh firewall add portopening tcp #### "VNC"
```

Replacing #### with the port.

Answer (score 0):

See the source code of Windows firewall (posted on google groups, Win32)

Comment: <sarcasm>link please</sarcasm>