# Letting my application use some ports - firewall issues

Tags: windows, firewall, multicast

My application uses a few ports for multicasting and other purposes.  By default, Windows Firewall blocks this (I'm on Windows 7).

I saw that the firewall can be controlled through API:
[What API calls are involved in opening a port in the Windows Firewall?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/802687/what-api-calls-are-involved-in-opening-a-port-in-the-windows-firewall)

but my application typically is not running with administrative rights, so I guess I couldn't use that at run-time.

What is the recommended way of making my app "just work" without the user having to manually add a firewall rule?

Should I just add firewall rule at install time?  Is there anything else I should be thinking about to get my application to "just work"?

BTW I only care about Windows 7 and Windows 2008 R2, 64bit versions, if that makes any difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Should I just add firewall rule at
>   install time?

Yes.